# docx4j library is supporting specific version of MS word

Tags: jaxb, docx4j

I am using below dependency of docx4j library. I am programmatically generating **doc file** using several templates in Java and it is working fine for specific version but As I am changing anything on existing templates using higher version or office 365 Microsoft word, it is allowing me to download the file but on opening it, it is showing that this file is corrupt file.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>docx4j-parent</artifactId>
        <version>8.1.4</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

I Have gone through docx4j official forum as well, they are suggested to change the version. So I have upgrade the version from ***8.1.4 to 8.1.6*** . Now there is no such CORRUPT FILE error but now I am getting error on console that I am pasting below here.

```
    org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Range problem
at com.plutext.merge.DocumentBuilder.a(DocumentBuilder.java:783) ~[Enterprise-8.1.0.3.jar:na]
at com.plutext.merge.DocumentBuilderIncremental.addBlockRange(DocumentBuilderIncremental.java:12) ~[Enterprise-8.1.0.3.jar:na]
at com.se.qdo.document.managment.service.DocumentServiceImpl.mergeDocument(DocumentServiceImpl.java:415) [classes/:na]
at com.se.qdo.document.managment.service.DocumentServiceImpl.downloadProposal(DocumentServiceImpl.java:221) [classes/:na]
at com.se.qdo.document.managment.controller.DocumentController.downloadProposal(DocumentController.java:32) [classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) [spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) [spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) [spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878) [spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792) [spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) [spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) [spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) [spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) [spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) [spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) [spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at brave.servlet.TracingFilter.doFilter(TracingFilter.java:65) [brave-instrumentation-servlet-5.8.0.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) [spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) [spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) [spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118) [spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158) [spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:130) [spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) [spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) [spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) [spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) [spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) [spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) [spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.ExceptionLoggingFilter.doFilter(ExceptionLoggingFilter.java:50) [spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at brave.servlet.TracingFilter.doFilter(TracingFilter.java:82) [brave-instrumentation-servlet-5.8.0.jar:na]
at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.LazyTracingFilter.doFilter(TraceWebServletAutoConfiguration.java:145) [spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:93) [spring-boot-actuator-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at com.se.qdo.document.managment.component.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:40) [classes/:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_251]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_251]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_251]
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Attempt to set incorrect parent value SdtBlock
at org.docx4j.wml.P.setParent(P.java:427) ~[docx4j-openxml-objects-8.1.6.jar:na]
at com.plutext.merge.n$c.walkJAXBElements(n$c.java:23) ~[Enterprise-8.1.0.3.jar:na]
at com.plutext.merge.n$c.walkJAXBElements(n$c.java:31) ~[Enterprise-8.1.0.3.jar:na]
at org.docx4j.TraversalUtil.<init>(TraversalUtil.java:271) ~[docx4j-core-8.1.6.jar:na]
at com.plutext.merge.n.a(n.java:200) ~[Enterprise-8.1.0.3.jar:na]
at com.plutext.merge.n.a(n.java:15) ~[Enterprise-8.1.0.3.jar:na]
at com.plutext.merge.DocumentBuilder.a(DocumentBuilder.java:45) ~[Enterprise-8.1.0.3.jar:na]
... 105 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to upgrade your Docx4j Enterprise jar(s), from 8.1.0.3.  Our current release is 8.1.0.7.